# Integrate Paypal and Paypal Express with PayPal REST API

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I try to integrate Paypal as a payment method.
When the User clicks on "checkout", it should be able that the user click's on 'direct to paypal' to do the express checkout. Or going the "normal" way, entering his shipping data and clicks on the last page "pay with paypal"

I follow the Paypal REST API documentation and the express checkout works fine. But I didn't get the "normal" checkout to run.

The problem isn't in the backend. So all backend operations (create payment, accept payment, etc.) running well.

But in the frontend I'm getting errors.

My Code for the Express checkout is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.6.1">
//....

if (jQuery('#paypal_express_btn_div').length > 0) {
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox'
        payment: function(resolve, reject) {
            var orderId     = jQuery("#orderPostId").val();
            // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
            var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = ajaxObject.ajaxURL;
            paypal.request.post(
                    CREATE_PAYMENT_URL,
                    {
                        action: 'create_paypal_payment',
                        orderId: orderId,
                    }
                )
                .then(function(data) { 
                    resolve(data.paymentID); 
                })
                .catch(function(err) { 
                    reject(err); 
                });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            //After the reload, a confirm page will be shown
            window.location = data.returnUrl;
        },

        onCancel: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.redirect();
        },          
    }, '#paypal_express_btn_div');
}
```

As I said, this works well. 
When the user clicks the button, the method "create_paypal_payment" runs on the backend. The payment get's created and when the payment is created, the paypal window get's shown to the user.
Now he can confirm the payment by clicking "next". Then (after the page reload) a confim page is shown to the user (with all payment and shipping data) and when he clicks "confirm payment" everything is fine.

But now I try to do the payment at the end of the order. (So the user has entered his shipping data etc.)

The first steps running well. So I can create the payment in the backend. 
But now I'm getting an error when I try to run the payment execute method in the "onAuthorize" Action. My method "executePayPerPayPalBasic" will not be executed. I'm getting directly an error.

My Code:

```
if (jQuery("#paypal_btn_div").length > 0) {
    var RS_IB_PAYMENT_URL = ajaxObject.ajaxURL;
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox'
        commit: true, //button "pay now" in the paypal window
        payment: function(resolve, reject) {
            var orderId     = jQuery("orderPostId").val();
            // Set up the payment here, when the buyer clicks on the button
            paypal.request.post(
                    RS_IB_PAYMENT_URL,
                    {
                        action: 'create_paypal_payment',
                        orderId: orderId,
                    }
                )
                .then(function(data) { 
                    resolve(data.paymentID); 
                })
                .catch(function(err) { 
                    reject(err); 
                });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            // Execute the payment here, when the buyer approves the transaction
            var payerID         = data.payerID;
            var paymentID       = data.paymentID;
            var paymentToken    = data.paymentToken;
            var returnUrl       = data.returnUrl;

            paypal.request.post(
                    RS_IB_PAYMENT_URL,
                    {
                        action: 'executePayPerPayPalBasic',
                        orderId: orderId,
                        payerID: payerID,
                        paymentID: paymentID,   
                        paymentToken: paymentToken,
                        returnUrl: returnUrl
                    }
                )
                .then(function(data) { 
                    var paypallink  = data.data["PERMALINK"];
                    window.location = paypallink;                       
                })
                .catch(function(err) { 
                    reject(err); 
                });
        }
    }, '#paypal_btn_div');      
}
```

The error:

> "Error: window.paypal<["./node_modules/post-robot/src/drivers/receive/types.js"]/exports.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPES<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:3319:40
>   receiveMessage@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1444:13
>   messageListener@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1462:13
>   "

Another strange thing is, as I understand, normaly the "commit" parameter should handle if the paypal button is "pay now" or "next".
Because of this, I'm not set the parameter in my express checkout (because I want the "next" button) and setting the parameter to true in my normal checkout.
But since I used the commit Parameter 1 time. I always getting the "pay now" button. Even in my Express Checkout Button. 
I have tried to set the parameter to false manually. But it doensn't work.

I tried this with Firefox, Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.
The error only occurs on Firefox.
In Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge it works like a charm.

But on each of these three Browsers the Button Text has the Text "pay now" and never shows "next".

Also, all payments are marked as Paypal Express Payments. Is there any Parameter to check my second code als 'normal' payment. Or is it normal, that when I do the payment with the checkout.js all payments are marked as Express Payment?

Where is my failure? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hey, I develop `checkout.js` so I'd love to help. Do you have this code hosted somewhere I can try it? Also, which browser are you seeing the error in?

Comment: Hi, currently I have the code only locally in a bigger system wich I can't put only at this time. But I try to create a example where the error occurs. I updated my question with the Browser support (shame on me that I forgot to test and write that before). Also I've updated my question, because all payments getting marked as "paypal express".

Comment: Can you let me know which specific version of Firefox, and I'll try it too

Comment: I use the Version 50.1.0 of Firefox

Comment: Did you change something? Because I was going to create an example for you. But now it seems to work fine in firefox :-) I will update my process an do some tests again. If you changed something, that it works now. THANKS!

Comment: I didn't change a thing! Wonder if it was just some temporary problem with the sandbox, or with the cookies in your FF instance. Anyway glad it works now!

Comment: Okay :-D Now I have only one question. Both Payments are marked as Paypal Express payment. Is that normal when I use the checkout.js or I do something wrong?

Comment: That's correct.